# MYSQLi SELECT statement malformed or misordered

Tags: php, select, mysqli

**Using the following table "technotes":**

[image: sample of table being used]

**And, using the following SQLi Query:**

```
SELECT *  
FROM 
  `technotes` 
WHERE 
  `techgroup` LIKE '%dispatch%' OR 
  `techgroup` LIKE '%30243542%' AND 
  `expires` >= '2014-12-18' AND 
  `viewed` NOT LIKE '%30243542%'
```

What was expected was that alertid's: 23324325 & 23546576 (1st and last one) would be returned. But instead i am getting record 1,3,4,5 being returned. I am missing something in the order of operation or some other component in the SQLi select statement is malformed but not sure what. Can someone advise what I have left out or need to change so this works properly?

Comment: Is 'expires' a datetime field?

Comment: As a first step, I would add parentheses around the conditionals to make sure precedence was correct. I'm not sure if MySQL gives OR or AND higher precedence.

Comment: "expires" field type is set as "date"

Comment: Encompass the first 2 OR conditions in parentheses

Comment: you're using `or` and `and` without any `()` to specify your desired parsing order: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

Comment: The problem is the "NOT LIKE"  clause, when you use NOT LIKE '%30243542%' Others will qualify and pass that condition because all other fields are not like that (let me say they are empty ),  this is the second condition which is valued with statement `expires` >= '2014-12-18'. Again they pass this too.

Comment: Ok guys, I guess I was having trouble locating where best to place the parentheses, but between Michael's comment, Mihai's as well as @MarcB I did get it straight now. Which of you wants the credit for the answer? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *  FROM 
  `technotes` 
WHERE 
(`techgroup` LIKE '%dispatch%' OR `techgroup` LIKE '%30243542%') 
AND `expires` >= '2014-12-18' 
AND (`viewed` NOT LIKE '%30243542%' OR ISNULL(`viewed`) )
```